# How to encrypt the data using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a use case where I want to encrypt my data when I persist the data in storage like Datalake store of Azure or Aws bucket using Spark. Is there a way to perform encryption using Spark? Please do not suggest to use binary format. Thanks!

Comment: You should encrypt your storage in Azure/S3... That's completely independent of Spark, though you need a auth secret to read and write into encrypted storage